# Xcode Test target not finding a class in the Main Target

Tags: swift, xcode

Consider a Main Target hierarchy:

```
[Project Name]
    --> Sources
        --> StatusUtils.swift
```

It does show in the `Project navigator`:

[image]

Here is the declaration in the file `StatsUtils.swift`:

```
class StatsHandler {

    static var enabled = true
    typealias Num = Float32
    typealias Data = [Num]
    let name: String
    let maxSize: Int
    var skips: Int
```

But when attempting to run a Test that class is not found:

[image]

[image]

Why would a Main Target class not be visible to the Test Target?

**Update** I neglected to mention that the `@Testable <projectName` is already in the test class

```
import XCTest
@testable import hybrid
```

Also: `Allow testing Host Application API's` is already checked:

[image]

Comment: Did you import module as testable?

Comment: @Asperi  good comment - I did neglect to mention that had been done: updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This solution does not need to check target membership**

When unit testing Swift files you should not import individual Swift files.
What you should do is use the `@testable import` statement in the unit test class to give the unit test class access to all of the application's Swift files.

**1. Make sure Host Application for test target**

ProjectNameTests > General > Testing > Host Application > Check Allow testing Host Applications APIs

**2. Make sure that Enable Testability is set to Yes**

Projects > Build Settings > Build Options > Enable Testability > YES

**3. Add `@testable import ProjectName`** on your test case

Comment: "Allow testing Host Application API's" is already checked

Comment: Oh - but `Enable Testability` was _not_ enabled for `Release` target.  Man..

Answer (score 0):

You can "Check" Test Target in **Target Membership** menu for `StatUtils.swift` to be accessible in Test Target.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update to the accepted answer:  the *2* "Enable Testability" was not set on the `Release` target.  Here is the screenshot

[image]

.. and after updating the `Release` to Yes

[image]